# How to convert System.IO.StreamReader to System.Xml.XmlReader in C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

My Console aplicattion created in C# has no rights to write in folder, only read.
The folder contains all XML archives in a different server.
The application must read all XML files, read/recover some important information inside the archive (those XML dont have a regular schema).
Insert those information into an Oracle database, and move next.

For the schema problem I generate some classes to receive all important nodes:

```
/* 
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ImportaXMLBILL.SchemaXMLBILL
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "House")]
    public class House
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "UID")]
        public string UID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Overlay")]
        public string Overlay { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OverlayUID")]
        public string OverlayUID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Paper")]
    public class Paper
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "PaperTag")]
        public string PaperTag { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "PaperFullName")]
        public string PaperFullName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "PaperUID")]
        public string PaperUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "CPaperName")]
        public string CPaperName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "CPaperUID")]
        public string CPaperUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "HouseUID")]
        public string HouseUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OverlayUID")]
        public string OverlayUID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Revision")]
    public class Revision
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Label")]
        public string Label { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "License")]
    public class License
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SystemUID")]
        public string SystemUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerUID")]
        public string OwnerUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerFullName")]
        public string OwnerFullName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerTag")]
        public string OwnerTag { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerDescription")]
        public string OwnerDescription { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerBaseUID")]
        public string OwnerBaseUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "HouseUID")]
        public string HouseUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OverlayUID")]
        public string OverlayUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "PaperUID")]
        public string PaperUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "RevisionLabel")]
        public string RevisionLabel { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Unit")]
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "UnitName")]
        public string UnitName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "XValues")]
        public string XValues { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "LastModUser")]
        public string LastModUser { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "LastModDate")]
        public string LastModDate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TagPattern")]
        public string TagPattern { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ValuePattern")]
        public string ValuePattern { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LinkInfo")]
        public LinkInfo LinkInfo { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "LinkInfo")]
    public class LinkInfo
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "LinkOrder")]
        public string LinkOrder { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Static")]
        public string Static { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SystemUID")]
        public string SystemUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerUID")]
        public string OwnerUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerFullName")]
        public string OwnerFullName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerTag")]
        public string OwnerTag { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerDescription")]
        public string OwnerDescription { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerBaseUID")]
        public string OwnerBaseUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "LicenseUID")]
        public string LicenseUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "HouseUID")]
        public string HouseUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OverlayUID")]
        public string OverlayUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "PaperUID")]
        public string PaperUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "RevisionLabel")]
        public string RevisionLabel { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "XValues")]
        public string XValues { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "StatusLink")]
        public string StatusLink { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "StatusXLink0")]
        public string StatusXLink0 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "StatusXLink1")]
        public string StatusXLink1 { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "LastModUser")]
        public string LastModUser { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "LastModDate")]
        public string LastModDate { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Head")]
    public class Head
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "House")]
        public House House { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Paper")]
        public Paper Paper { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Revision")]
        public Revision Revision { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "License")]
        public List<License> License { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Query")]
    public class Query
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ColName")]
        public string ColName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ColDescription")]
        public string ColDescription { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "SystemUID")]
        public string SystemUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerUID")]
        public string OwnerUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerFullName")]
        public string OwnerFullName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerTag")]
        public string OwnerTag { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerDescription")]
        public string OwnerDescription { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OwnerBaseUID")]
        public string OwnerBaseUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "HouseUID")]
        public string HouseUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "OverlayUID")]
        public string OverlayUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "PaperUID")]
        public string PaperUID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "RevisionLabel")]
        public string RevisionLabel { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TagPattern")]
        public string TagPattern { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "License")]
        public List<License> License { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Query")]
        public List<Query> Query { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "xml_init")]
    public class xml_init
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Head")]
        public Head Head { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }

}
```

But in the execution time:

```
   protected void ReadPO(string filename)
   {
      // Create an instance of the XmlSerializer class;
      // specify the type of object to be deserialized.
      XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xml_init));
      /* If the XML document has been altered with unknown
      nodes or attributes, handle them with the
      UnknownNode and UnknownAttribute events.*/
      serializer.UnknownNode+= new XmlNodeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownNode);
      serializer.UnknownAttribute+= new XmlAttributeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownAttribute);

      // A FileStream is needed to read the XML document.
      FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open); <-- This line
```

An exception is throwing:
Message = "The acess '\\carnaval\apl_$\Billings\Document.xml' was denied."

--> There is not time to ask for permissions <---

So i'm trying unsuccessfully to just "Read" the XML in:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"\\carnaval\\apl_$\\Billings\\Document.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
```

And fill my Classes With:

```
public object Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, string encodingStyle);
```

And a new thown shows to me:
Compiler Error CS1503

Argument 'number' cannot convert from TypeA to TypeB

The type of one argument in a method does not match the type that was passed when the class was instantiated. This error typically appears along with CS1502. See CS1502 for a discussion of how to resolve this error.

**Any suggestions on how to proceed in this case?**

Comment: You can't "convert" a StreamReader to an XmlReader, but you can **[create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.create?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xmlreader-create(system-io-textreader-system-xml-xmlreadersettings))** an XmlReader from one. See [How to Convert a StreamReader into an XMLReader object in .Net 2.0/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41012/3744182) which is still correct 14 years later.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: You do not need a streamreader.  Use : Xm;Reader.Create("\\carnaval\\apl_$\\Billings\\Document.xml")